# Laravel Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::createToken does not exist

Tags: laravel

After I create a new user I try to  create token via

```
$user = User::where('user_id', '=', $userid)->get();
$user->createToken('name')->accessToken;
```

Then i got the following error:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::createToken does not
>   exist.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are calling for a *collection* of `users` when you use the `get()` method, which won't have the `createToken` method (which is exactly what the error message is telling you).

You need to call for a *single* **User** model:

```
$user = User::find($userid);
```

And then, assuming you have the `createToken` method on your **User** model, this should work.

EDIT per comments:

You may have some other issue that is preventing the creation of the token in addition to the original issue of the collection vs an object.  Try to create the token first:

```
$user = User::find($userid);
$token = $user->createToken('name');
```

Then if you will either get an error (if your `createToken` method is incorrect, or the parameter 'name' is not correct, etc), or you will have the token, and can then draw the `accessToken` from the new variable, `$token`.

Like this:

```
$accessToken = $token->accessToken
```

Either way, this will give you the diagnostics to bug hunt.

Comment: thanks but now i got this error Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: That's because there is no `user` with the `id` that you are pushing with `$userid`.  Try the code with a known user id like `User::find(1)`.  This is a standard error that you will need to check for - (if isset($user), or use findOrFail, or similar)

Comment: but data is not empty i got all of user data after i try to return $user = User::find($userid);

Comment: If you dump `$user` *before* you try to `createToken`, do you have a `user` object?

Comment: OK, if you have a single user object, and it has data within, you should not get the non-object error.  Try to create the token immediately after getting the user **without* trying to access the `accesstoken` field.  It may be trying to get the access token without correctly creating the token.  One minute I will edit my answer to explain